# [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00911 in VBScript

Tags: oracle, vbscript, hp-uft

When I use the query directly it's works, but when I run in it with VBscript this error occurs.

The connection with de DB works.

```
global_OracleConn = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")

global_OracleConn.Open connectionString

query = "UPDATE DB.TabelX SET X_DT_ = SYSDATE + 360, "_
    &"X_Amount_MAX_ID = 100, X_Amount_IN_REQUEST = '1', X_NUM = 15000,"_
    &"X_VALUE_LIMIT = 15000, SCORE = 0, 
    &"WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT X_ULTIMA_ID FROM DB.TabelY "_
    &"WHERE OU_NUM IN ('"&varID&"'));" 

global_OracleConn.Execute(Query)
```

I tried use others breaklines or put all in one line, but the error still occurs.

Comment: You don't appear to have opened any databases. `connectionString` is not defined above.

Comment: The sample code you posted is both incomplete and broken. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're facing and post that code (copy/paste, do not type from memory) and the full, unaltered error message you get from that code.

Comment: Sorry, the connection was ommited

      `code: 
connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " &_
 "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="& HOST &")(PORT="& PORT &")) " &_
 "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="& SERVICE &"))); uid="& USR &";pwd="& PASS &";" `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. Remove the semicolon at the end from your SQL string
2. The quoting is wrong. You missed a double quote after `SCORE = 0,`
3. Ancient Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) for ages. Use the ODBC driver from Oracle
4. Use prepared statement with bind parameters, i.e.

Comment: Thank you, it was the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Is there a reason for down voting? (For even an accepted answer)